# Angular Firestore - how to get a field and key from firestore?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

In my angular firebase project. Through query, I want to get a document which should have device field as "mobile" and is ordered by "timestamp". The ts file, html file and firestore data like below:

The console.log shows device and timestamp doesn't exist on type 'Query'. Can you tell me how can I realise it through using firestore query. And if you call tell what the type Query looks like, it will help me to understand.

firestore:

```
---messages
      |---xdfjialdfd
      |        |----device: mobile
      |        |----timestamp: 12345
      |
      |---xdiflldkd
               |----device: pc
               |----timestamp: 34323
```

component.html:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="text-center">
                {{ showFollowingPosition() }}
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
  showFollowingPosition() {
      this.afs.collection('messages', ref => {
          let query : firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
          query = query.where('device', '==', "mobile");
          query = query.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(1);
          console.log(query.timestamp);
          console.log(query.device);
          return query;
        });
  }
```

Thanks